# How do I store text files in the Android Directory on Installation in a Xamarin Project?

Tags: xamarin, installation, text-files, portable-class-library

I have a bunch of resource text files that I don't want to embed in my Xamarin Project. When I install my app I want to text files to be transferred to the phones android directory at

```
data/data/$ProjectName/files
```

Which is the FileSystem's LocalStorage. How do I set up my Xamarin project to do this?

Currently I put all of the files in a folder and set the files to CopyAlways, and when I build they go into the project's Debug Folder. But when I run the project on my phone, nothing is showing up in the localstorage folder. My Xamarin project is PCL and I am exporting to an Android Phone with SDK 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy them as [Android Assets](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/) instead.  Then your app can either read them directly from Assets, or can copy them to local storage.  Your app has to explicitly write things to local storage - there is no automated build action that will do this for you.

Comment: Wow that is surprising there is no build action! Thanks

Comment: Where are the Assets stored on installation to the phone? Is this constant?

Comment: Everything that is deployed to the phone is contained within the app bundle (this is true of iOS too).  It's not like a Windows app where you can create a custom installer that writes files all over the filesystem.